# Como calcular a idade de uma pessoa no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tsql

Suponha a tabela `Pessoa` e o campo `DataNascimento`.

Em uma consulta SQL, qual a melhor forma de se calcular a idade de uma pessoa em formato inteiro na linguagem T-SQL do **SQL Server**?

Comment: As respostas que usam datediff calculam a idade matemática, mas a idade como é aceita em formulários depende do dia do mês.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pensando na vida real, em quando queremos saber nossa idade, a gente simplesmente pensa da seguinte maneira:

se eu nasci em 1990: tenho 29 anos ou tenho 28 anos (Diferença em anos entre o ano do meu nascimento e o ano atual).

Terei 29 se eu já fiz aniversário neste ano (se a data atual em relação a dia e mês já passou da minha data de aniversário) e;

terei 28 se ainda não fiz aniversário este ano.

Seguindo este raciocínio, conseguimos chegar a esta lógica, em sql:

```
DECLARE @dataNascimento Date = '2016-1-1';
DECLARE @dataReferencia Date = '2020-12-31'

select 
(
    CASE 
        WHEN 
        MONTH(@dataReferencia) > MONTH(@dataNascimento) -- *1
        OR
        -- *2
        (
            MONTH(@dataReferencia) = MONTH(@dataNascimento) 
            AND DAY(@dataReferencia) >= DAY(@dataNascimento) 
        )
    THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, @dataNascimento, @dataReferencia) 
    ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, @dataNascimento, @dataReferencia) -1 END
) AS IDADE;
```

*1 : Basta que O mês da data atual seja maior que o mês do meu aniversário, que devemos considerar já ter feito aniversário no ano corrente (dataReferencia).
*2 : Ou, como o mês da data atual ainda não é maior que o mês do meu aniversário, os meses devem ser iguais e o dia do mês atual maior ou igual o dia do meu aniversário.

Agora é só testar com alguns exemplos.

Obs: considerando quem nasceu no dia 29/02, esta pessoa sempre faria aniversário no dia 01/03 para anos não bissextos (?) . A lógica aplicada segue este raciocínio.

Comment: A forma natural de contarmos a idade é a mais assertiva. Todas as fórmulas que envolvem operações de divisão falham em algum momento.

Answer (score 22):

O jeito mais correto que conheço é:

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, DataNascimento, GETDATE()) / 365.25)
```

---

Esta forma é mais correta que utilizar as horas de um ano (como @rodrigorgs sugeriu) pois a hora do dia em que a query é executada não é considerada. Em alguns casos, se uma pessoa faz aniversário no dia seguinte ao dia de hoje, a query considerando as horas irá informar como se a pessoa já tivesse feito aniversário, quando na verdade não fez (a não ser que ela seja executada exatamente no horário 00:00).

Exemplo:

```sql
DECLARE @DataNascimento DATETIME = '1991-12-12'
DECLARE @Hoje DATETIME = '2013-12-11 17:00:00' -- exemplo de horário da função GETDATE()
                           -- funciona corretamente se alterado acima para hora 00:00:00

SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, @DataNascimento, @Hoje) / 365.25) -- retorna 21, idade correta
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, @DataNascimento, @Hoje) / 8766 -- retorna 22
```

Comment: Esta forma falha em algumas situações, por exemplo, considerando a @DataNascimento `07/01/1987` e @Hoje `07/01/2016`, retorna 28 quando o correto é 29. Isto porque o valor mais preciso para divisão deveria ser `365.23076923074`.

Comment: @ricidleiv, de onde saiu esse número todo? Sei que um ano possui 365 e 4 horas, porém no banco, como isso se comporta para fins matemáticos?

Comment: @bruno101 O número se dá porque um ano não tem exatamente 365 dias e 4 horas, mas 365 d 06h 09 mim 13 s.

Comment: @ricidleiv, aquele valor é a conversão desses 6d, 9 min e 13s então, é isso?

Answer (score 18):

Prefiro ir pro lado mais extenso e seguro e usar uma função com lógica tradicional de cálculo de idade, para não ter problemas com arredondamento e fórmulas:

```sql
SELECT YEAR(dHoje)-YEAR(dNasc)-IIF(MONTH(dHoje)*32+DAY(dHoje)<MONTH(dNasc)*32+DAY(dNasc),1,0)
```

Você pode trocar o dHoje por GETDATE() (CURDATE() no MySQL) ou mesmo CURRENT_TIMESTAMP quando for aplicar na base de dados. Fiz com variáveis o exemplo para que se possa testar facilmente usando DECLARE (entretanto, lembre de por @ antes das variáveis).

Notas:

- Usei 32 como multiplicador do mês apenas como boa prática (potência
  de 2), mas sendo de 31 pra cima está ok;
- Como não consideramos hora no cálculo de idade, o IIF está ajustado para que o numero de anos de idade "suba" exatamente no dia do aniversário da pessoa;
- Lembre-se de que neste caso estamos considerando o aniversário dos nascidos em 29 de fevereiro como sendo 1 de março nos anos não bissextos. Caso prefira de outra forma provavelmente vai ter que acrescentar uma condição especial para isso;
- Finalmente, caso queira usar isso em outros "dialetos" de SQL, como no MySQL por exemplo, troque o IIF por IF.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode pegar a data de hoje usando `getdate()` e subtrair a data do registro banco usando `DATEDIFF`:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, DataNascimento, getdate()) / 8766 FROM Pessoa
```

8766 é o número de horas em um ano (aproximadamente, pois há anos bissextos).

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate.

Answer (score 4):

O método mais preciso de calcular a idade no `SQL Server` é considerar o dia de nascimento e o dia base do cálculo e calcular a diferença de anos com `DATEDIFF`. A função abaixo realiza o cálculo:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('calcular_idade', 'FN') IS NULL
BEGIN
  EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION calcular_idade() RETURNS INT AS BEGIN RETURN 1 END');
END;
GO

ALTER FUNCTION calcular_idade(@nascimento DATE,
                              @data_base  DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @idade      INT;
  DECLARE @dia_inicio INT;
  DECLARE @dia_fim    INT;

  SET @data_base = ISNULL(@data_base, GETDATE()); -- Caso seja nula considera a data atual
  SET @idade = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @nascimento, @data_base);
  -- Deve ser feito dessa forma por conta do ano bissexto
  -- Por exemplo: dia 16/06 ficará 616 e 14/12 ficará 1214
  SET @dia_inicio = (MONTH(@nascimento) * 100) + DAY(@nascimento);
  SET @dia_fim = (MONTH(@data_base) * 100) + DAY(@data_base);

  -- Se ainda não passou no ano base
  IF @dia_fim < @dia_inicio
  BEGIN
    SET @idade = @idade - 1;
  END;

  RETURN @idade;
END;
GO
```

A chamada com a data atual (28/07/2017) resultado 29 anos para a data de nascimento 16/06/1988 seria a seguinte:

```
SELECT dbo.calcular_idade('1988-06-16', '2017-07-28') AS idade
```

Resultando em:

```
╔═══╦═══════╗
║   ║ idade ║
╠═══╬═══════╣
║ 1 ║ 29    ║
╚═══╩═══════╝
```

---

> [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184325(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Substitui `NULL` pelo valor de substituição especificado.

---

> [`GETDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188383(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o carimbo de data/hora do sistema do banco de dados atual como um valor `datetime` sem o deslocamento de fuso horário do banco de dados. Esse valor é derivado do sistema operacional do computador no qual a instância do SQL Server está sendo executada.

---

> [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189794(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna a contagem (inteiro com sinal) dos limites especificados de `DATEPART` cruzados entre os parâmetros especificados `startdate` e `enddate`.

---

> [`MONTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187813(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna um inteiro que representa o mês da `date` especificada.

---

> [`DAY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms176052(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna um inteiro representando o dia (o dia do mês) da `date` especificada.

Comment: Show! Testado e aprovado!

SELECT dbo.calcular_idade('1973-07-01', GETDATE()) AS idade

Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @dataNasc datetime ='1973-06-03'

SELECT 
idade= convert (int, convert( decimal,convert (varchar( 10), getdate(), 112)) /10000 - convert( decimal,convert (varchar( 10), @dataNasc , 112)) /10000 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Caros amigos, eu acabei desenvolvendo este script para rodar em Access:

```
iif(year(Date())-year([DATA DE NASCIMENTO])<=0,0,iif(month(date())>month([DATA DE NASCIMENTO],year(Date())-year([DATA DE NASCIMENTO],iif(day(date())>day([DATA DE NASCIMENTO],year(date())-year([DATA DE NASCIMENTO],(year(date())-year([DATA DE NASCIMENTO])-1))) as IDADE
```

Rodou perfeitamente na versão 360, onde [DATA DE NASCIMENTO] deve ser o campo na tabela ou view (consulta) que contenha a data de nascimento da pessoa a ser calculada a idade. Testei até com Bi-Sexto e funciona bem.

Answer (score -1):

Fiz de um modo diferente, bem simples, mas não sei se pode trazer algum tipo de erro, com relação a ano bissexto ou outra coisa, deem uma olhada e comentem, ok
se tiver algum problema, se puderem me comunicar seria muito bom!

```
declare @data1 datetime set @data1 = '02/02/2000'
declare @data2 datetime set @data2 = '12/28/2000'
declare @data3 datetime set @data3 = '12/28/1977'


select year(GETDATE() - @data1)-1900 union 
select year(GETDATE() - @data2)-1900 union 
select year(GETDATE() - @data3)-1900
```

Comment: Considerando alguém nascido no dia 29/02 em ano bissexto, desta forma ele considera aniversário já no dia 28/02.

Answer (score -2):

Precisei agorinha e fiz de duas formas:

```
declare @dt_nasc datetime = '2002-10-16',
  @agora datetime = getdate(),
  @idade int
select @idade = year(@agora)-year(@dt_nasc)
if dateadd(year,@idade,@dt_nasc) > @agora
  set @idade -= 1
print @idade
```

ou dentro do select...

```
select idade = year(getdate())-year('2002-10-16')-
  case when
    dateadd(year,year(getdate())-year('2002-10-16'),'2002-10-16') > getdate() then 1
    else 0
  end
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).